# Parse Android tree json object (Family tree)

Tags: java, android, json, tree

I have tree json object(Family tree).

I have refer this link for parsing : 
[Android parse json tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851190/android-parse-json-tree)

But i got problem while fetching data from arraylist.

My all code in below link :

https://app.box.com/s/9ca7bhp04y078wduumoj7j0wkaa4rw40

I want to display json data in tree structure and for that i am using https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView library.

Please guide me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1). Import `GSON` library to your gradle project:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

2). Generate your m,odels using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
**`Child.java`**:

```
public class Child {
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @Expose
    private String firstname;
    @Expose
    private String lastname;
    @Expose
    private Integer sex;
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @Expose
    private List<Child_> children = new ArrayList<Child_>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param firstname
     * The firstname
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param lastname
     * The lastname
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The sex
     */
    public Integer getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param sex
     * The sex
     */
    public void setSex(Integer sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The image
     */
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param image
     * The image
     */
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The children
     */
    public List<Child_> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param children
     * The children
     */
    public void setChildren(List<Child_> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

**`Child_.java`**:

```
public class Child_ {

    @Expose
    private String id;
    @Expose
    private String firstname;
    @Expose
    private String lastname;
    @Expose
    private Integer sex;
    @Expose
    private String image;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param firstname
     * The firstname
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param lastname
     * The lastname
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The sex
     */
    public Integer getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param sex
     * The sex
     */
    public void setSex(Integer sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The image
     */
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param image
     * The image
     */
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

**`Datum.java`**:

```
public class Datum{
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @Expose
    private String firstname;
    @Expose
    private String lastname;
    @Expose
    private Integer sex;
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @Expose
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The firstname
     */
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param firstname
     * The firstname
     */
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The lastname
     */
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param lastname
     * The lastname
     */
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The sex
     */
    public Integer getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param sex
     * The sex
     */
    public void setSex(Integer sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The image
     */
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param image
     * The image
     */
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The children
     */
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param children
     * The children
     */
    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

**`Respone.java`**:

```
public class Respone{
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = new ArrayList<Datum>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The data
     */
    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param data
     * The data
     */
    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

3). From your file:

```
String strResponse = "...";
```

After this line do next:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Respone response = gson.fromJson(strResponse, Respone.class);
```

4). Check your `response` variable.

**UPDATED**

5). Here is your json structure:

```
{
    "data":[
        {...},
        {
            ...,
            "children":[
                ...,
                "children",
                ...
            ]
        },
        {...}
    ]
}
```

6). Create `SelectableItem.java`:

```
public class SelectableItem extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<String>{
    private final String mText;

    public SelectableCategoryItem(Context context, String text) {
        super(context);
        mText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode treeNode, KalturaCategory c) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectable_item_layout, null, false);

        TextView someTextViewOrAnythingElse = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.some_textview_or_anything_else));

        someTextViewOrAnythingElse.setText(mText);

        return view;
    }
}
```

7). Build your three:

```
public TreeNode buildThree(){
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(response);
    SelectableItem item = new SelectableItem(YourActivity.this, "Response");
    node.setViewHolder(item);

    for(Datum datum : response.getData()){
        TreeNode nodeDatum = new TreeNode(datum);
        SelectableItem itemDatum = new SelectableItem(YourActivity.this, "Datum: " + datum.getFirstName() + " " + datum.getLastName());
        nodeDatum.setViewHolder(itemDatum);

        for(Child child : datum.getChildren()){
            TreeNode nodeChild = new TreeNode(child);
            SelectableItem itemChild = new SelectableItem(YourActivity.this, "Child: " + child.getFirstName() + " " + child.getLastName());
            nodeChild.setViewHolder(itemChild);

            for(Child_ child_ : child.getChildren()){
                TreeNode nodeChild_ = new TreeNode(child_);
                SelectableItem itemChild_ = new SelectableItem(YourActivity.this, "Child: " + child_.getFirstName() + " " + child_.getLastName());
                nodeChild_.setViewHolder(itemChild_);
            }
        }
    }

    TreeNode root =  TreeNode.root();
    root.addChildren(node);

    return root;
}
```

8). Create your `ThreeView`:

```
AndroidTreeView treeView = new AndroidTreeView(YourActivity.this, root);
treeView.setDefaultAnimation(true);
treeView.setDefaultContainerStyle(R.style.TreeNodeStyleCustom);
```

9). Add your `Tree` to layout:

```
RelativeLayout threeContainer = findViewById(R.id.some_container);
threeContainer.addView(treeView.getView());
```

Comment: Alex : Here which TreeNode class is used?